# Cin.getline Won't Print Right nor Work Properly

Tags: c++, printing, cin

In my following code I am trying to add a line of information into my text file. Currently I have tried 3 different options yet none have completely worked. (cin.get, cin.getline and cin >>)

When I tried to use the cin.getline(name,60) for instance, It will accept the information but I get a few print out errors (not compiling errors but they display wrong).

1) If I type the assignment as **1 - Web** it accepts it in the cin.getline but if I type **1 - Web Design Part 1 Application** and I hit enter my program starts looping endlessly of the menu options and doesn't take the information.

2) When I print my file it prints out weird

ex:

```
Accept from the following options to proceed.
1) Add Assignment
2) Remove Assignment
3) Print Listing
4) Quit
1

In our system we show Class information.
Enter class name with class number like so: (MCS 220)
MCS 299

Enter the Project Number < - > then Project title like so: (1 - Web Design     Part Application)
1 - Web

Enter the due date for assignment like so: (05-12-2015)
05-12-2015
```

PRINTS:

```
COMPSCI 181,Project 5 - Web page development,04-14-2015
MCS 220,Project 3 - Java fundamentals,04-15-2015
MCS 220,Project 4 - Array, 04-15-2015
, Project CS 299,  - We-05-1 // Prints this line
```

Any help is appreciated! I can honestly say I am rusty when it comes to reading files. This is the first time I have added to a file so I hope you can explain why I am having this issue and maybe help me fix it.

Below is my current function that adds a line and my main file code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


int options = 0;
char name[60];
//string name; //this was when I attempted cin >>
//string assign; // this was when I attempted cin >>
char assign[60];
string date;
string lines;

void addProject () {
cout <<"Enter class name with class number like so: (MCS 220)"<<endl;
    cin.getline(name, 60);
    cin.ignore();
    //cin >> name;
    cout <<endl;
    cout <<"Enter the Project Number < - > then Project title like so:" <<
            " (1 - Web Design Part Application)"<<endl;
    cin.getline(assign, 60);
    cin.ignore();
    //cin >> assign;
    cout <<endl;
    cout << "Enter the due date for assignment like so: (05-12-2015)"<<endl;
    char cMonth[3];
    char cDay [3];
    char cYear[5];

            cin.get(cMonth,3, '-');
            cin.ignore(2, '-');
            cin.get(cDay, 4, '-');
            cin.ignore(2,'/');
            cin.get(cYear, 5);

    //input into file
    ofstream readFile;
    readFile.open("list.txt", std::ios::app);
    readFile << name << ", " << "Project " << assign << ", "
                    << cMonth <<"-"<< cDay <<"-"<< cYear<< endl;
}

//BEGIN MAIN CODE
int main() {

ifstream readFile("list.txt");


if (!readFile){
cout <<"I am sorry but we could not process "<<
     "the file information."<<endl;
}


    menu();
    cin >>options;
    cout <<endl;

    cout <<"In our system we show Class information."<<endl;
    //read and output the file
    while (options != 4)
    {

    //print the listing
    if (options == 3){
    while (getline(readFile, lines)){

    cout << lines<<endl;
       }
    }

    // Add Assignments
    if (options == 1){
            addProject();
     }

    menu();
    cin >>options;
    cout <<endl;

    }//end while
    readFile.close();
}
```

Comment: For starters: you never check if the input fails or not.  Knowing which input first fails would do a great deal toward solving your problem.

Comment: If you mean like troubleshooting each cin individually then I have. If I comment out all the cin.getline except the first one, It accepts the input and then loops continuously through my menu options. Same for the second cin.getline(assign) as well.

Comment: I don't mean troubleshooting.  Even in a program which seems to work, you have to verify that the input succeeded before using the value you input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code. The issue was having the cin.ignore placed right by next cin variable.

```
char name[256];

char pnum[20];
char title[256];
string date;
string lines;

void addProject () {
    cout <<"Enter class name with class number like so: (MCS 220)"<<endl;

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.getline(name, 256, '\n');

    //char upperName = toupper(name); /*
          for (char *caps = name; *caps != '\0'; ++caps)
            {
                    *caps = std::tolower(*caps);
                    ++caps;
            }

    cout <<endl;
    cout <<"Enter the Project Number: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(pnum, 20, '\n');
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout<<"Enter the Project's title next: "<<endl;
    cin.getline(title, 256, '\n');
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout <<endl;

    cout << "Enter the due date for assignment like so: (05-12-2015)"<<endl;
    char cMonth[3];
    char cDay [3];
    char cYear[5];

            cin.get(cMonth,3, '-');
            cin.ignore(2, '-');
            cin.get(cDay, 4, '-');
            cin.ignore(2, '-');
            cin.get(cYear,5);

    //input into file
    ofstream readFile;
    readFile.open("list.txt", std::ios::app);
    readFile << name <<",Project "<< pnum << " - " << title <<
                    ", "<< cMonth <<"-" <<cDay <<"-"<< cYear<< endl;
}
```